# Why does this shared library not have an expected dependency?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a shared library, `libfunc.so`, that has a dependency on another shared library (specifically `libuv.so`, but I think that the specific library is not relevant to the question). I.e. when I run `ldd libfunc.so`, I want to see the dependency from `libfunc.so` to `libuv.so`.

This is the code I want to compile to `libfunc.so`:

```
#include <uv.h>

int func() {
  uv_timespec64_t now;

  uv_clock_gettime(UV_CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

  return 0;
}
```

...I compile it like this:

```
$ cc --version && cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall -c -o func.o func.c
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o -fpic -ggdb -Wall -luv
$
```

...when I run `ldd libfunc.so` I do not see the desired dependency on `libuv.so`:

```
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff827ae000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f14b291e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f14b2b54000)
$
```

...i.e. I was wanting to see something along the lines of:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbbdca000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f781b25c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f781b034000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f781b2a2000)
```

My question is: **why doesn't a dependency on `libuv.so` show up, and what do I need to do to create that dependency?**

My understanding is probably rudimentary and incomplete, but I thought that creating a dependency relationship was along the lines of 1) write code that calls a function from a (shared) library, 2) compile object code, 3) create (shared) library from object code while linking with a library that defines the missing symbol.

Inspecting `libfunc.so`, I do see expected undefined symbols for `libuv` symbols:

```
$ nm libfunc.so | grep U
0000000000002000 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
                 U __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4
                 U uv_clock_gettime
$
```

---

For some context, I'm trying to create a MVCE from larger project. Specifically, that larger project creates a shared library that has a dependency on `libuv`. When I run `ldd` on the larger project's shared library, though, it does show a dependency on `libuv` (that's where I got the output for the "desired" ldd output, above).

The larger project is too large for me to post here on Stack Overflow, but from inspecting its `make` output, I believe that my MCVE is compiling/linking with the same flags. E.g. a few compile lines and the link line from the larger project are:

```
cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall   -c -o file1.o file1.c
cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall   -c -o file2.o file2.c
cc -shared -o libplugin.so file1.o file2.o -fpic -ggdb -Wall -luv
```

(there are more files compiled that comprise `libplugin.so`, but the above subset conveys the gist of it -- the compile flags are uniform for all the compiled files)

---

**Update:** If I add a call to `uv_close()` in my shared library's code, the desired dependency relationship shows up! I.e.:

```
#include <uv.h>

int func() {
  uv_timespec64_t now;

  uv_clock_gettime(UV_CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  uv_close(NULL, NULL); // <= Adding this line causes the desired dependency to show up in ldd

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall -c -o func.o func.c
$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o -fpic -ggdb -Wall -luv
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1e323000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f412b761000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f412b539000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f412b7a1000)
$
```

Can someone help me understand this observation? Why does calling `uv_clock_gettime()` vs. `uv_close()` behave this way with regards to the dependency relationship created in the shared library?

---

Update: I wanted to explore @WeatherVane's comment RE: optimization a little more. Here again, my understanding is probably rudimentary and incomplete, but I thought that if I compiled with `-O0`, it would force the compiler to not optimize anything out, and therefore induce the dependency even when my shared library only calls `uv_clock_gettime()`. But reality didn't match this idea: returning `func.c` to only calling `uv_clock_gettime()` and compiling everything with `-O0`, I still see no dependency on `libuv`. I.e.:

```
$ cc -fpic -ggdb -O0 -Wall -c -o func.o func.c # Note the -O0
$ cc -shared -O0 -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv # Note the -O0
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff8e724000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fee6f03e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fee6f274000)
```

---

I wanted to explore @Barmar's suggestion of excluding the possibility of optimizing-out by printing the value of `now`, but even that version of code resulted in there not being the desired dependency. I.e.:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uv.h>

int func() {
  uv_timespec64_t now;

  uv_clock_gettime(UV_CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  printf("%" PRId64 "\n", now.tv_sec);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall -c -o func.o func.c
$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd72bdf000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0a89964000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0a89b9a000)
```

---

Exploring @EmployedRussian's suggestion, the `readelf` output is:

```
$ readelf -Ws /usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1 | grep uv_close
   337: 0000000000013766   427 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 uv_close
   735: 0000000000013766   427 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 uv_close
$ readelf -Ws /usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1 | grep uv_clock_gettime
   341: 00000000000136a0   178 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 uv_clock_gettime
  1120: 00000000000136a0   178 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 uv_clock_gettime
$
```

---

I'm updating this post with some observations based on @EmployedRussian's answer because they're relevant, but cumbersome to add as a comment.

With the version of the shared library that calls only `uv_clock_gettime`, the use of the linker `-y` option reveals:

```
$ cc -shared -Wl,-y,uv_clock_gettime,-y,uv_close -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv
/usr/bin/ld: func.o: reference to uv_clock_gettime
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so: definition of uv_close
$
```

...and with the version of the shared lib that references both `uv_clock_gettime` and `uv_close`, the linker `-y` option reveals:

```
$ cc -shared -Wl,-y,uv_clock_gettime,-y,uv_close -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv
/usr/bin/ld: func.o: reference to uv_close
/usr/bin/ld: func.o: reference to uv_clock_gettime
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so: definition of uv_close
```

...which aligns with @EmployedRussian's explanation of symbols referenced vs. symbols found vs. `DT_NEEDED`.

Also, with the version of the shared lib that references only `uv_clock_gettime`, using the linker `--no-as-needed` flag did indeed "force" inclusion of the dependency:

```
$ cc -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe312cf000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f36fe4f8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f36fe2d0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f36fe538000)
$
```

Comment: Is there no dependency because the function `int func()` is optimised to `return 0;`? It has no observable behaviour. BTW it should be `int func(void)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - interesting suggestion regarding being optimized-out; that hadn't occurred to me. But please check out the update I made: randomly picking another `libuv` symbol, `uv_close()`, to call from my shared library, I was able to create the desired dependency relationship. I'd like to learn what's behind this behavior: it's not clear to me what's the relevant difference between `uv_clock_gettime()` and `uv_close()` here...?

Comment: Doesn't the update answer your question? The function now has a side-effect, but previously had none..

Comment: @WeatherVane - yes, I guess the update answers the "what do I need to do to create that dependency" part of the question. :) But I'm not sure I understand what's going on here, so there's probably still an opportunity for me to learn something from more fully-fleshed answer. I'm not sure I fully grok what constitutes a function that can be optimized out vs one that can't.

Comment: If the code behaves exactly the same with some of it removed (and its dependencies) then it can be optimised. A simple example is a local variable `int var;` that is never used, and the compiler won't even allocate any storage space for it.

Comment: The difference is that `uv_close()` has a side effect, but `uv_clock_gettime()` doesn't. Calling a function with no side effects, and not using the results, means the call can be optimized away.

Comment: If you added code to print the value of `now`, the optimization would not be possible and you'd see the dependency.

Comment: RE: optimizing-out, if a function meets the criteria for being optimized out, then wouldn't its listing as an undefined symbol also be removed? I.e. when `uv_clock_gettime()` is optimized-out, I can understand the conclusion that it would have no dependency on `libuv.so` in `ldd`...but then wouldn't its listing as an undefined symbol also be removed from `nm`? I.e. if I run `nm libfoo.so` shouldn't there be no `U uv_clock_gettime` entry?

Comment: @Barmar - your comment RE: removing the possibility of optimizing out by printing the value of `now` made sense to me, but unfortunately didn't align with observation: when I added `printf("%" PRId64 "\n", now.tv_sec);`, the resulting output of `ldd libfunc.so` still showed no dependency on `libuv`.

Comment: Is `uv_clock_gettime` a macro?

Comment: @WeatherVane They didn't use any optimization options. Would it really do this level of optimization with minimal optimization?

Comment: @WeatherVane Would a macro be in `nm` output?

Comment: @WeatherVane - confirming: `uv_clock_gettime` is not a macro. It has a declaration in `uv.h`: `UV_EXTERN int uv_clock_gettime(uv_clock_id clock_id, uv_timespec64_t* ts);`

Comment: The difference is _probably_ due to the nature of `uv_close` and `uv_clock_gettime` symbols, though I can't imagine what the difference could be. Please update your question with the output from `readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 | grep -e ' (uv_close|uv_clock_gettime)'`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian -- the specific command you noted returned nothing to stdout; I tried instead to grep on `uv_close` and `uv_clock_gettime` individually, and updated the question accordingly -- I hope this still gives you appropriate information. One other thing I noticed: I needed to grep `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1` instead of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` because the latter did not have the `uv_clock_gettime` symbol. I'm actually going to post a separate question on that specific topic...stay tuned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One other thing I noticed: I needed to grep `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1` instead of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` because the latter did not have the `uv_clock_gettime` symbol.

That is *probably* the answer. I am guessing that

1. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` is being used at link time, and
2. Your GCC is configured to pass `-Wl,--as-needed` by default.

If both of these are true, then, when you link `func.o` that *doesn't* reference `uv_close`, the linker finds `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` but discovers that it doesn't satisfy any symbols, and thus doesn't record it as `DT_NEEDED` for `libfoo.so`.

When you change `func.o` to also require `uv_close`, the linker observes that `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` is necessary to satisfy that symbol, and does record it in the `DT_NEEDED` tag for `libfoo.so`.

---

To confirm these guesses, link `libfoo.so` with `-Wl,-y,uv_clock_gettime,-y,uv_close` flag. This should show you which binaries reference and which define the two symbols.

You can also link with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` -- in that case `libuv.so.1` will show up regardless of whether it satisfies any symbols.

Comment: Thank you; I learned a lot from your answer. RE: `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1` vs. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1`, I have posted another question on this issue; it's unexpectedly weird...I wonder if you have any insight based on your understanding of the workings of the linker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756000/what-causes-shared-object-dependency-to-change-after-wsl-shutdown-restart

Comment: A key question here is then about `libuv.so`, which is what the linker will actually be searching for.  Presumably there are symbolic links of that name in different places in the library search path on the OP's system, pointing to the different `libuv.so.1`s.  The different shared libraries could be better accommodated if that were not so (but maybe not altogether cleanly even then).

Comment: @JohnBollinger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756000/what-causes-shared-object-dependency-to-change-after-wsl-shutdown-restart explains what's happening with the two versions of `libuv`.