# What causes shared object dependency to change after WSL shutdown/restart?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, apt, package-managers

In an Ubuntu 22.04.3 WSL instance, I'm compiling a shared library that links to `libuv`.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 WSL, straight out of the Microsoft Store, doesn't include `libuv`. Installing it via the `apt` package manager installs version 1.43.0-1 at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so`:

```
$ find /usr -name libuv.so 2>/dev/null
$
$ sudo apt-get install -y libuv1-dev
# ...
$ find /usr -name libuv.so 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so
$
$ apt list | grep libuv1

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libuv1-dev/jammy,now 1.43.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libuv1/jammy,now 1.43.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
$
```

The code for the shared library is a simplification/MCVE of a larger project. It requires `libuv` symbols not available in version 1.43.0-1 (specifically, `uv_timespec64_t` and function `uv_clock_gettime`). Therefore, I install a newer version that includes these symbols. Because no newer version is available to the `apt` package manager, I follow the build/install instructions at its [README.md](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/README.md). Note that this appears to install the new version at `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so`, i.e. it does not overwrite the version installed with the `apt-get` package manager:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git && cd libuv && git checkout v1.45.0 && mkdir -p build && (cd build && cmake .. -DBUILD_TESTING=ON) && cmake --build build && (cd build && ctest -C Debug --output-on-failure) && sudo cmake --install build
# ...
$ 
$ find /usr -name libuv.so 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so
/usr/local/lib/libuv.so
$
```

Now, I have two versions of `libuv` in my Ubuntu WSL instance: version 1.43.0-1 at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so` and version 1.45.0 at `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so`.

This is the shared lib that I'm compiling:

```
#include <uv.h>

int func() {
  uv_timespec64_t now;

  uv_close(NULL, NULL);
  uv_clock_gettime(UV_CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile as follows:

```
$ cc --version && cc -fpic -ggdb -Wall -c -o func.o func.c
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o  -fpic -ggdb -luv
$
```

The shared library dependencies, as reported by `ldd`, are below. Note that it is linking against version 1.43.0-1, located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so` (`/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib`):

```
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc74bdb000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f323f071000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f323ee49000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f323f0b1000)
$
$ ls -ld /lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 22 13:36 /lib -> usr/lib
$
```

But, if I shut down (`wsl --shutdown`) and restart my Ubuntu WSL instance, then without (knowingly) changing the environment or touching the compiled shared lib, **`ldd` now reports that it links against version 1.45.0, located at `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so`**:

```
$ # I've started this new Ubuntu WSL instance after shutting down the last instance with `wsl --shutdown`
$ 
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd655d000)
        libuv.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1 (0x00007fe8db267000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe8db03f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe8db2b8000)
$
```

My question is: **why does the `libuv`, that is "chosen" to be linked against, change after the shutdown/restart of the WSL instance?**

Is this WSL-specific, where something is adjusted in the environment with each new instance (and what is the "something" that is adjusted)? Or would I observe similar behavior on any Linux PC after a physical shutdown/restart?

---

From [How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path), I know how to query the linker's ordered search paths:

```
$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

...this implies that the linker would prefer `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1` (which, as noted before, links to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1`) over `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1`. This explains the pre-shutdown output from `ldd`, but does not explain the post-restart output of `ldd`.

---

One more possibly-related thing I'm aware of is `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. However, there is no change to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or any file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` after shutting down/restarting the Ubuntu WSL instance.

---

**Update:** @EmployedRussian's comment appears to essentially be the answer to this question. I'm updating this question with relevant findings:

```
$ # After starting a new instance of Ubuntu WSL:
$ ldconfig -Np | grep libuv
236 libs found in cache `/etc/ld.so.cache'
        libuv.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1
$ # No change after running `sudo apt-get install -y libuv1-dev`
```

```
$ # After running `sudo apt-get install -y libsdl2-dev`:
$ ldconfig -Np | grep libuv
        libuv.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1
        libuv.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so
```

```
$ # After manually installing libuv v1.45.0 (acknowledged, this is a Really Bad Idea (TM)):
$ # No change
```

```
$ # After manually installing libuv 1.45.0 and running `sudo ldconfig`:
$ ldconfig -Np | grep libuv
        libuv.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libuv.so.1
        libuv.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1
        libuv.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libuv.so
        libuv.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so
```

The same pattern can be observed by shutting down/restarting Ubuntu WSL (instead of running `sudo ldconfig`). Moreover, the difference in the output of `ldd ./libfunc.so` can also be reproduced before/after running `sudo ldconfig`. I can therefore infer that shutting down/restart of Ubuntu WSL triggers invocation of `ldconfig`, which explains the difference in behavior of where `ldd` resolves the `libuv` dependency before and after the Ubuntu WSL shutdown/restart.

Comment: The `ld` search path (which you examined) has _nothing_ to do with where `ldd` (`man ld.so`) looks for libraries at runtime. My guess: rebooting runs `ldconfig` to rebuild `/etc/ld.so.cache`. Run `ldconfig -Np` before and after reboot and compare the outputs.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - your comment turned out to be the answer; please see the updates to my question for relevant findings.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - is the `ld` search path for compile-time linking, whereas `ldd` is for runtime linking? Otherwise, could you expand on that comment "The ld search path has nothing to do with where ldd looks for libraries at runtime"? (if I understand correctly from `man ld.so`, `ldd` _prints_ the dependencies, but the "rules" are governed by `ld.so` (or `ld-linux.so`))...but I'm not sure I understand any relationship to `ld`.

Comment: There is no such thing is "compile-time linking". The distinction is between static linking (done by the (static) linker, usually `/usr/bin/ld`) and dynamic linking (done by `ld-linux.so`), AKA runtime loading. The static linker _can_ affect search paths used by the dynamic/runtime loader when using `-rpath` flag, but in general their search paths are completely independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because no newer version is available to the apt package manager, I follow the build/install instructions at its README.md. Note that this appears to install the new version at `/usr/local/lib/libuv.so`.

This is a Really Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>.

You can download the 1.43 source package and check how it is configured; then configure 1.45 the same way. That should result in putting the binaries into the same location. However, that is *also* a bad idea, as it screws up package manager and dependencies, and sooner of later leads to a broken system.

---

A better idea is to configure and install non-default packages into a non-default location, with something like `./configure --prefix /usr/local/libuv-1.45`.

This library will then *not* be used by a random build; you would have to specifically point to it in order to use it. Typically you would do something like:

```
make LVTOP=/usr/local/libuv-1.45 CFLAGS='-I${LVTOP}/include' \
  LDFLAGS='-L${LVTOP}/lib -rpath=${LVTOP}/lib'
```

to direct compiler to use `${LVTOP}/include` for the headers, and the linker to use `${LVTOP}/lib` for both static (`ld`) and dynamic (`ld-linux.so`) linking.

When used that way, the extra package doesn't interfere with the system in any way, doesn't affect your other builds, and doesn't magically change configuration across reboots.

---

P.S. This doesn't directly answer the question of "why did reboot change something?", but see my comment above for my best guess of why that happened.

Comment: Thank you; I learned a lot from your answer again. I've somewhat recently learned about the Unix Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and also Linux distributions/packages, so I'm glad you touched on this notion of different versions of libraries "conflicting" due their placement at different locations in the filesystem as well as breakage of package management/dependencies by "manually" installing builds outside of package management. The recommendation to install to user-specified, non-default locations seems like the best approach to this situation.

Comment: "You can download the 1.43 source package and check how it is configured" -- is there a "standard" way to do this in Unix/Linux, or is this something users need to figure out on a per-package basis? If the former, how do you check the configuration of a package?

Comment: @StoneThrow It's a `dpkg`-specific thing. I don't remember the details, but google points to https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/12/15/howto-to-rebuild-debian-packages/

Comment: This makes me remember: back in the old days, there used to be build servers with a "magic" environment, where build dependencies had been carefully configured, and nobody remembered exactly how to reproduce the build environment. Putting the pieces together, from your answer, I suppose that in those days, creating the "magic" build environment was some combination of installing some packages by package-manager and manually installing other packages...effectively screwing up that PC's package management and dependencies, and creating a hard-to-reproduce build environment.